# In login shell but rvm is not a function

Tags: shell, authentication, rvm

```
$ shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'
Login shell
$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
-bash: type: write error: Broken pipe
```

However:

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

I removed ~/.rvm/ and tried installing again using `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto` but that doesn't help.
It's a remote Ubuntu 13.04, that I have ssh'd into, authenticating with keys.  Any advice?

Comment: try: `env | grep rvm_is_not_a_shell_function`

Comment: Thanks @mpapis , `$ env | grep rvm_is_not_a_shell_function # => rvm_is_not_a_shell_function=1`.  Got any advice off the back of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sourcing the ~/.rvm/bin/rvm script twice.  In the process of uninstalling and reinstalling, it once happened to not modify ~/.bash_profile.  I then did this manually.  A second uninstall/re-install dance then produced a ~/.bash_profile of:

```
source ~/.bashrc

# (lines added by me)
if [ -f /ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm ]; then
  source '/ubuntu/.rvm/bin/rvm'  > /dev/null
fi

# (lines added by RVM installer using: curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles)    
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: `bin/rvm` is executable script to be executed via `PATH` search when `rvm` functions is not loaded, you are not supposed to source it

Comment: @mpapis I agree that I shouldn't have but the last line in that `~/.bash_profile` is added by the rvm setup and it's sourcing it so "you are not supposed to source it" can't be correct.

Comment: @mpapis I think we should probably delete this question and answer anyway, what do you think?

Comment: you are not alone that tried to source `bin/rvm`, you should accept your answer - that way others can learn from it.